# Is there a phpmyadmin equivalent for nginx?

Tags: debian, nginx, mariadb, phpmyadmin

I've installed LEMP (w/ Mariadb) on a Debian 9 (Stretch) on a Raspberry Pi.  I've only had experience with Apache before this and phpmyadmin to manage the databases.  I can't find tutorials to add phpmyadmin with LEMP.  When I go to install phpmyadmin it seems to force an install of Apache.

I can manage my databases from the command line but obviously I'd prefer phpmyadmin if possible.

Comment: Searching for “phpmyadmin nginx” lists a number of tutorials. I haven’t tried any, but [DigitalOcean’s](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server) seems pretty good.

Comment: I've come across that tutorial but I'm hesitant to start because A) I'm on Mariadb not MySQL.  B)  When I `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` it says it is going to install Apache.

Comment: Try `apt-get install` with `--no-install-recommends`.

Comment: Yeah that seemed to do the trick.  I'll go forward with the tutorial and see how it goes.